# How to include custom customer attribute in to magento admin customer grid?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, grid-serlization, grid, customer-grid

I added customer mobile no while customer register in the registration page.

The created mobile no is attribute stored in `eav_attribute` table with `entity_type_id` 1.

I tried to add these field in the admin grid view on the customer page.

I edit the `grid.php` file and adding these lines to `grid.php`

```
$this->addColumn('Telephone', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Telephone'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'index'     => 'billing_telephone'
    ));
$this->addColumn('mobile', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Mobile'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'index'     => 'mobile'
    ));
```

The label is shown in the view after Telephone, but the value for the mobile no is not retrieved in the grid.
How can i retrieve the value of mobile number in the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `_prepareCollection()` method in customer grid class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid` and add `->addAttributeToSelect('mobile')`

Also, you shouldn't edit core files directly.

Comment: Thank you it's work, yeah i know directly edit the core file is not good practice, How can i perform this task?

Comment: Google override magento block :)